# Python: How can I draw a bar graph in python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

My goal is to create a bar graph with my .csv data to see the relationship between work year (x) and wage (y) grouped by gender (separate bars).

First off, I want to group the variable'workyear' into three groups: 
(1) more than 10 years, (2) just 10 years and (3) less than 10 years
Then I would like to create the bar graph with gender (1=female, 0=male)

Part of my data looks like this:

```
...    workyear gender wage 
513         12    0  15.00
514         16    0  12.67
515         14    1   7.38
516         16    0  15.56
517         12    1   7.45
518         14    1   6.25
519         16    1   6.25
520         17    0   9.37
....
```

To do this, I tried to replace the variable's value into three groups and I used matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#load data 
df=pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data.csv', index_col=None)
print(df)
df.sort_Values("workyear", ascending=True, inplace=True)

#parameters
bar_width = 0.2

#replacing Education year -> Education level grouped by given criteria.
#But I got an error.
df.loc[df.workyear<10, 'workyear'] = 'G1'
df.loc[df.workyear==10, 'workyear'] = 'G2'
df.loc[df.workyear>10, 'workyear']='G3'

#plotting
plt.bar(x, df.education[df.gender==1], bar_width, yerr=df.wage,color='y', label='female')
plt.bar(x+bar_width, df.education[df.gender==0], bar_width, yerr=df.wage, color='c', label='male')
```

I want to see the bar graph like this (please consider '+' as a bar):

```
y=wage|                 + +
      | +        +      + +
      | +      + +      + +
      | + +    + +      + +
      |_______________________ x=work year (3-group)
        >10     10       10<
```

But this is what I actually got... (yes. all errors)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "data.py", line 21, in <module>
df.loc[df.workyear>10, 'workyear']='G3'
in wrapper
res = na_op(values, other)
in na_op
result = _comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, x, y)
in _comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY
result = lib.scalar_compare(x, y, op)
File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 769, in pandas._libs.lib.scalar_compare (pandas\_libs\lib.c:13717) 
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Could you please advice me?

Comment: Convert `df.workyear` to a numeric type before.

Comment: Try this `df.apply(pd.to_numeric)` right before the plotting.

Comment: @Goyo : did you mean to convert df.workyear like this? -> df.loc[df.workyear>10, 'workyear']='3'? Since I am a beginner in python. I am not sure how to solve this at all.

Comment: @Tom Wojcik Thank you. But I got an error with 
    df.loc[df.workyear>10, 'workyear']='3'.

Comment: @Goyo: I still got the same error.

Comment: What do you see after printing `df.info()`?

Comment: @Tom Wojcik: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 534 entries, 0 to 533
Data columns (total 3 columns):
workyear    534 non-null int64
gender          534 non-null int64
Wage         534 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2)
memory usage: 12.6 KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more direct way :

```
df['Age']=pd.cut(df.workyear,[1,13,14,100])
df['Gender']=df.gender.map({0:'male',1:'female'})
df.pivot_table(values='wage',index='Age',columns='Gender').plot.bar()
```

for :

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: there was no 10 in your sample data :) . for you it is [min,10,11,max]  . ( is included, ] is excluded.

Comment: I accidently deleted my previous comment. Thank you so much again @B. M. I actually have more data (n=534). I changed the code using [min,10,11, max], but I still have an error.

Comment: I edit because I realize than mean is not necessary since (G','gender') is a unique key. Is it better ?

Comment: Or, is there any other ways to cut the variable into three groups? Let's say, the first group includes 0 ~9.9, and the second group has 10 only, and the last group works more than 10.1~

Comment: [min,9.9,10.1, max] ?

Comment: The error has been created in line with the first code df['G']=pd.cut(df.workyear,[min,9.9,10.1,max]).  
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py", line 130, in cut
    if (np.diff(bins) < 0).any():
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1926, in diff
    return a[slice1]-a[slice2]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Comment: replace min and max by adequate values.

Comment: pd.cut use only ints, so use [1,10,11,100]. the central category is only 10.   if problem persist, give a link to your data, I will check.

Comment: May I ask how to change the gender 0 and 1 into female and male?